# Makefile to run a command line program

Tags: makefile

I'm a newbie to Makefiles. I'm trying trying to run this PDF merger (sedja-console) from a Makefile but can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. Any help greatly appreciated.

```
SEDJA=$(shell which sedja-console)

.PHONY: sedja

sedja: all.pdf

all.pdf: *.pdf
   $(SEDJA) merge -b one_entry_each_doc -f *.pdf -o all.pdf
```

Comment: What did you expect? What happens instead?

Comment: I'm expecting all the PDF files in the current folder to be merged into one file, all.pdf. Instead I get the following error:     merge -b one_entry_each_doc -f *.pdf -o all.pdf
/bin/sh: 1: merge: not found
Makefile:8: recipe for target 'all.pdf' failed
make: *** [all.pdf] Error 127

Comment: Nevermind. Found the problem. A stupid spelling mistake. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Note that once you will have run this once, it will probably fail the second time because `all.pdf` will be part of the source PDF files... You should probably use `$(filter-out all.pdf,$(wildcard *.pdf))`, instead of `*.pdf`.

Comment: You should also use `$^` instead of `*.pdf` in the command itself, to get the list of dependencies.  That way you only need the `filter-out` in one place.

Answer (score 0):

Spelling SEJDA correctly fixed the problem.

```
SEJDA=$(shell which sejda-console)

.PHONY: sejda

sejda: all.pdf

all.pdf: *.pdf
   $(SEJDA) merge -b one_entry_each_doc -f *.pdf -o all.pdf
```